# Convert Application from React 0.13.3 to React 0.14

Tags: reactjs

I have developed a React Application in which below mentioned modules I have used.

```
"babel-runtime": "^5.1.10",
"core-js": "^0.9.6",
"flux": "^2.0.1",
"fs": "0.0.2",
"griddle-react": "^0.2.13",
"humps": "0.0.1",
"invariant": "^2.0.0",
"joi": "^6.5.0",
"keymirror": "^0.1.1",
"material-ui": "^0.9.0",
"moment": "^2.10.6",
"normalizr": "^0.1.2",
"react": "^0.13.3",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.23.1",
"react-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.18",
"react-bootstrap-table": "^0.9.7",
"react-color-picker": "^2.1.6",
"react-data-components": "^0.4.0",
"react-datepicker": "^0.11.4",
"react-day-picker": "^1.0.1",
"react-dnd": "^1.1.1",
"react-document-title": "^1.0.0",
"react-flex-layout": "^0.9.2",
"react-intl": "^1.2.0",
"react-pure-render": "^1.0.1",
"react-router": "^0.13.3",
"react-select": "^0.6.3",
"react-spinner": "^0.2.1",
"react-validation-mixin": "^4.1.0",
"selectn": "^0.9.6",
"underscore": "^1.8.2",
"validator": "^3.40.1",
"webpack": "^1.11.0",
"whatwg-fetch": "^0.7.0",
"xml2js": "^0.4.12"
```

Now I want to upgrade React 0.13.3 to 0.14 I know facebook has already released the document but I am not clear about it if I will update the react with 0.14 then what about dependencies how new react version is applicable to dependencies modules how I can upgrade dependencies as well.please guide me.

Comment: A good place to start is to react the blog post detailing the changes between the versions, [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could run a regex over your `node_modules` folder `package.json` files after running `npm update`.

Since we know that `^version` [means](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-1-2-3-0-2-5-0-0-4) "Compatible with version" the regex would be `"react": "^0.14.0"` to check what packages are compatible with React 0.14.0.

If you're on an Unix based OS, one (untested) way would be:

```
grep -ER --include="**/package.json" "\"react\": \"\^0\.14\.0\"" project_root_path/node_modules
```

Comment: Thanks romseguy for your input